# My phone shows no Pokemon but other people around me are finding them

Tags: pokemon-go

I am playing on an iPhone 6s and recently I was in a highly populated area with lots of people playing. I had Wi-Fi on and GPS was working, but my phone was not showing that I had any nearby.  I talked with some young men who told me there were at least 9 nearby.  Why wasn't my phone showing them?

Comment: this can also happen when the servers are overloaded, not much you can do there.

Comment: VTLO. This doesn't look like the same question to me. The proposed duplicate seems to be talking about Pokemon not spawning, whereas this question asks about Pokemon that are spawning for other people, but not the player. This runs directly counter to the common knowledge that Pokemon spawns are shared, so I think this is distinct.

Comment: That's exactly my question.  Thank you.  I shut my phone down and brought it back up, and now I can find Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the servers have a hiccup, and anyone with the app currently open will stop finding pokemon (they also won't be able to access gyms or claim items from pokestops).

Force closing the app and opening it up again resolves the problem. Either you'll see the same pokemon others are seeing, or you'll see the servers are down.